# More efficient way of looping over a multidimensional numpy array other than numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I have a nested array of shape: [200, 500, 1000].
Each index represents a coordinate of an image, eg array[1, 2, 3] would give me the value of the array at x=1, y=2, and z=3 in coordinate space. I have repeating values in the array in the range from 1-20,000. My goal is to find the x, y, and z coordinates of each of these values (they occur multiple times). Normally, I'd just loop over the array and ask at each point
`current_values = np.where(arr==current_index)` 
However, it's slow. So I tried cupy instead (`current_values = cp.where(arr==current_index)`), but it sometimes doesn't work at around the same index. For example, `current_values = cp.where(arr==current_index)` yields an empty array at current_index==760 on one run, and current_index==780 on another run. Keep in mind I am using the same data, so I am quite puzzled by this behaviour. The amount of errors is small I assume, because this only happens thrice in the loop, but it obviously still impacts my accuracy.

I have two questions:

1. Can I smartly restack my array and use a different function from .where so I don't have to use cupy?
2. What is causing these errors with cupy.where?

Comment: Please include a [mre]. It's unclear if you want a map of value to indices, and whether you want such a map for all values, or just repeated/duplicated values.

Comment: Keep in mind that the number of matching indices can vary with the value.  Which means the usual goal of a 'vectorized' result isn't possible.  Still if you reshape (temporarily) the data to 1d,  `bitcount` and `unique` may be useful. `unique` works with sorting to collect like values together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A completely different solution:

```
    array = np.random.randint(1, 20_001, (200, 500, 1000))
    flat_array = array.reshape(-1) # does not copy array
    sorted_index = np.argsort(flat_array)

    # Suppose you want to find all elements that have value 100
    left = bisect.bisect_left(sorted_index, 100, key=lambda x: flat_array[x])
    right = bisect.bisect_right(sorted_index, 100, key=lambda x: flat_array[x])
```

At this point, `flat_array[sorted_index[i]] = 100` for all values of `i` such that `left <= i < right`.

Each `sorted_index[i]` can be converted into a 3-dimensional index using:

```
np.unravel_index(sorted_index[i], array.shape)
```

So you also that that

```
array[np.unravel_index(sorted_index[i], array.shape)] = 100
```

for that same range of indices.

Note: By default `np.argsort` uses an unstable sorting algorithm.  If it's important that the indices be in increasing order, add `kind='stable'` to the sort call.

---

Changed to use `np.unravel_index` as suggested by @hpaulj. Fixed typo where I used `temp` instead of `sorted_index`.

Comment: or one could call `np.unique` on the flattened array. Side note: you may consider `array.ravel()` instead of `.reshape(-1)`.

Comment: @OlivierGauthé.  `np.unique` would give you one index of each value, but I'm not sure it can be used to find all the indices corresponding to a value.  The `inverse` result is an index into the `unique` array, not the original array.  And yeah, I know about `ravel()`, but its such a horrible name; `reshape()` is easier for me to remember.

Comment: There's an unravel function that converts 1d indices to 3d.

Comment: @hpaulj.  Ah, thank you.  I knew such had function had to exist, but couldn't find it. I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use numba to collect the indices in one pass.

See for example the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba.typed import List

@njit
def indices(data):
    nk, nj, ni = data.shape
    out = {}
    _data = data.ravel()
    for i in range(data.size):
        value = _data[i]
        if value not in out:
            out[value] = List.empty_list(np.int64)
        out[value].append(np.int64(i))
    return out

data = np.random.randint(0, 2000, size=(20,50,100), dtype=np.uint16)
res = {
    key: np.unravel_index(np.array(value), data.shape) 
    for key, value in indices(data).items()
}
print(res)
```

Note that I used the flat index in numba and unravel to the original shape later to make the typing easier in nopython mode of the numba jit.

Answer (score 0):

It's still pretty slow, but you *are* asking about 10 million indices.

You could do something like:

```
    array = np.random.randint(1, 20_001, (200, 500, 1000))
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    it = np.nditer(array, flags=['multi_index'])
    for value in it:
        result[value.item()].append(it.multi_index)
```

`result[value]` will now contain all the indices that have `value`.

Comment: In past testing, `nditer` has not improved iteration speeds.  You are still, doing `for value in it` thoussnds of times.

Comment: 100 million, in fact